# comparing filenames with dates and removing them after 30 days in linux/bash/unix

Tags: linux

for example if I have a directory with many files of different dates, and the dates are put with the file name. And if one of my files name is `tr_2017-12-05.html` and date on this file which is `2017-12-05` is 30 days older than today's date which is `2018-01-10`, the older file needs to be deleted. What would be the Linux script for it?

Comment: Please show what you have tried this far. Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

If file name have its real creation date use find to delete them

```
find /path/ -ctime +30 -exe rm -f {} \;
```

will delete file that are created on 30th day in the past & before

Comment: Thanks. Will try to see it works or it is what I am exactly looking for.

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. Could you tell me how to extract the date from my file name: tr_2017-12-05.html , to output 2017-12-05, and than deleting it if it is older than 30 days.

Comment: `-ctime` is not the file creation time, but the inode change time.  This may or not be the same as the file creation time.

Comment: You may find that `-mtime` is a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=./

for file in $(find $directory -maxdepth 1); do
    a='[^0-9]*([[:digit:]]{4}).([[:digit:]]{2}).([[:digit:]]{2})'
    [[ $file =~ $a ]];
    year=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    month=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    day=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    # echo "Year=$year Month=$month Day=$day"
    mydate=$year$month$day
    if [[ $mydate ]]; then
    [[ "$(date -d "$mydate" +'%s')" -gt "$(date -d "30 days ago" +'%s')" ]] && 
    echo rm -i "$file"
    fi
done
```

If the list of files match your expectations, remove the `echo` in the `rm` command.